# Array in Angular scope variable has only one member

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I am a beginner to AngularJS and thanks to the Angular community on Stackoverflow which is willing to help a newbie like me, I am learning it very well thanks a lot for that.

Today I would like to add a feature to the exercise I was doing yesterday (which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35625596/cannot-write-a-basic-controller-angularjs)). I would like to keep a record of the pairs of numbers that the user has typed in and show it as a list of lines. To do that, I introduce an array of number objects. Pressing the button adds the current pair to the array.

Currently, it seems like the array contains only member whatever I do to push new members to it. Can anyone help me find my mistake?

```js
var saApp = angular.module("saApp", []);

saApp.controller('numberController', function($scope) {
  $scope.numbers = [];

  $scope.number = {
    number1: 0,
    number2: 0,
    sumIt: function() {
      var numberObject;
      numberObject = $scope.number;
      return parseInt(numberObject.number1) + parseInt(numberObject.number2);
    }
  };

  $scope.pushIt = function() {
    if ($scope.number !== undefined)
      $scope.numbers.push($scope.number);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="saApp" ng-controller="numberController">
  <input type="text" ng-model="number.number1" placeholder="Enter a number here">

  <input type="text" ng-model="number.number2" placeholder="Enter another number here">

  <br />{{number.number1}} + {{number.number2}} = {{number.sumIt()}}

  <br />

  <br />
  <button ng-click="pushIt()">Push</button>

  <div ng-repeat="number in numbers">
    {{number.number1}} + {{number.number2}} = {{number.sumIt()}}

    <br />
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I'm checking if it's null

Comment: And even if I remove it, the array still has only one number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One change in your current code just clone the `$scope.number` before pushing into the `$scope.numbers` array.

```
 $scope. pushIt = function() {
            if ($scope.number !== undefined)
                $scope.numbers.push(angular.copy($scope.number));
        }
```

*Why we should clone before pushing.*

The $scope.number object is the same always thus all of the elements in the array will have the same $$hashkey and you will get this [error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=number%20in%20numbers&p1=object:3&p2=%7B%22number1%22:%224%22,%22number2%22:0,%22$$hashKey%22:%22object:3%22%7D)

So you should clone  or copy the object before pushing, so that the array has new element objects in it.

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/CskHCl80uN1Yz1I6LG0T?p=preview)

Comment: I was coming to this conclusion as I was attempting to solve the problem. And things work better if I change `numberObject = $scope.number;` to `numberObject = this;`.

Answer (score 1):

> Use `object` having keys as `input` fields to be pushed in `ng-repeat`. Every repeated object will have his own scope and will update biding values accordingly.

Try this:

```js
var saApp = angular.module("saApp", []);

saApp.controller('numberController', function($scope) {
  $scope.numbers = [];
  $scope.pushIt = function() {
    var obj = {
      number1: 0,
      number2: 0,
      sumIt: function() {
        return parseInt(this.number1) + parseInt(this.number2);
      }
    }
    $scope.numbers.push(obj);
  }
  $scope.pushIt();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="saApp" ng-controller="numberController">
  <button ng-click="pushIt()">Push</button>
  <div ng-repeat="number in numbers">
    <input type="text" ng-model="number.number1" placeholder="Enter a number here">
    <input type="text" ng-model="number.number2" placeholder="Enter another number here">{{number.number1}} + {{number.number2}} = {{number.sumIt()}}
    <br />
  </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/cjs2xd8h/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $scope.pushIt = function() {
        if ($scope.number)
            $scope.numbers.push($scope.number);
    }
```

Replace your pushIt function by this Code